# second section element moves to second row

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two `section` elements such as `<section class="first"></section><section class="rightarrow"></section>`. In the first section element I have menu and in second one there is an arrow pointing towards right. This arrow is placed at the top right corner of the first section element and also the first section element display is set to none. When I click on arrow then the menu appears and slide towards right side (which works) but the problem is when this first section is element is display set to block then the arrow goes to next row.

Can someone give me some example how can I keep arrow on the right side of the first element?

here is my css

```
.first {
position: relative;
border-right: 1px solid #666;
display: none;
left: -370px;
float: left;
}

.rightarrow {
float: left;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
margin-right: 1%;
margin-top: 2%;
figure {
    width: 31px; height: 80px;
    background: url(../../images/rightarrow.png) no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    //left: 0;
}
}
```

here is my html

```
<section class="column three first">
        <section class="row top topfirst">
            <span class="user">Helsinki, Suomi</span>
            <span class="comments user">Vaihda sijaintia</span>
            <section class="clear"></section>
        </section>
        <section class="row top topsecond">
            <figure>
                <img src="assets/images/user.png" />
            </figure>
            <span class="user">Matti Meikalainen</span>
            <span class="comments user">Kirjaudu ulos</span>
            <p><input type="text" class="searchbox" placeholder="Hae" /></p>
        </section>
        <section class="row topthird">
            Etusivu
        </section>
        <nav class="row accordion">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Uutiset</a>
                    <figure class="down"></figure>
                    <section class="clear"></section>
                    <ul class="inside">
                        <li><a href="">Fringilla Condimentum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Fringillau</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Curabitur</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Mollis</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Ipsum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lorem</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Fringillau</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Curabitur</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Mollis</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Ipsum</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Foorumi</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Kauppa</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Messut</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Asiakaspalvelu</a>
                    <figure class="down"></figure>
                    <ul class="inside">
                        <li><a href="">Tilaa lehti</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Muutos tilaukseen</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Lähetä uutisvinkki</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Anna palautetta</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Nakoislehti</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Nae meidat</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </section>
    <section class="rightarrow">
        <figure>
        </figure>
    </section>
```

here is my js

```
$('.rightarrow').on('click', function () {

    $('.rightarrow').animate({'margin-left': '366px'}, 1000);
    /*
    $('.first').animate({'left': '0px'}, 100, function () {

    });*/
    $('.second').animate({'margin-left': '10px'}, 1000, function () {

    });

    $('.first').css('display', 'block').animate({'left': '0px'}, 1000); 
  });
```

Comment: Have you considered using absolute positions and a positive z-index? Judging by the layout in the link, it might be more appropriate in my opinion...

Answer (score 0):

`display: block` means "nothing besides me in the same line", so you can't use that.

Create the arrow element as a child of `.first` (i.e. inside of the DIV). Instead of hiding it completely, show only the rightmost part (which contains the arrow). When the button is clicked, you can move the element into view.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your

```
$('.rightarrow').animate({'margin-left': '366px'}, 1000);
```

to

```
$('.rightarrow').css({'margin-left': '366px','position':'absolute','top':'20px';});
```

will help you in achieving what you are aiming for.